# Wordpress: How to import posts from one multisite blog into another?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I need to convert an old website to wordpress multisite with 4 blogs. Because I need to enter the old content manually, page by page, post by post, and because each blog has one category called press, with exactly the same posts on all 4 sites, I was wondering if there is a way to import these posts into the other 3 blogs after I finished inserting them into the first one, so I don't have to go through the same drudgery 3 more times?

Answer (score 1):

There are many plugins that help with import and export, have you checked that option?

If you are comfortable with MySQL you can insert the posts directly into the wp posts table. Keep in mind that the category ids are not the same.

BTW, you sure that a multisite is what you need? It's pain in the neck.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I exported the posts from the first blog via tools/export and then I imported them to the other 3 via tools/import.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I exported the posts from the first blog via tools/export and then I imported them to the other 3 via tools/import.